# How to make GWT Datagrid have its first column fixed and scroll horizontally and vertically

Tags: gwt, datagrid

Currently GWT DataGrid header does this trick with a fixed header row during a vertical scroll. Is there a way to acheive the same on an entire (first) column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented ScrolledGrid that freezes first column in DataGrid. You need to use it instead of DataGrid in order to make first column be frozen.

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ScrollEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ScrollHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DataGrid;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HeaderPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Yuri Plaksyuk
 */
public class ScrolledGrid extends DataGrid {

    private final Text cssText;
    private boolean addedClass = false;
    private int currentScrollLeft = 0;

    public ScrolledGrid() {
        cssText = Document.get().createTextNode("");

        StyleElement styleElement = Document.get().createStyleElement();
        styleElement.setType("text/css");
        styleElement.appendChild(cssText);

        HeaderPanel headerPanel = (HeaderPanel) getWidget();
        headerPanel.getElement().insertFirst(styleElement);

        final ScrollPanel scrollPanel = (ScrollPanel) headerPanel.getContentWidget();
        scrollPanel.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                int scrollLeft = scrollPanel.getHorizontalScrollPosition();
                if (scrollLeft != currentScrollLeft) {
                    StringBuilder css = new StringBuilder();
                    if (scrollLeft > 0) {
                        css.append(".ScrolledGrid-frozen {");
                        css.append("background-color: inherit;");
                        css.append("}");

                        css.append(".ScrolledGrid-frozen div {");
                        css.append("position: absolute;");
                        css.append("left: ").append(scrollLeft).append("px;");
                        css.append("width: ").append(getColumnWidth(getColumn(0))).append(";");
                        css.append("padding-left: 1.3em;");
                        css.append("padding-right: 0.5em;");
                        css.append("margin-top: -0.7em;");
                        css.append("white-space: nowrap;");
                        css.append("background-color: inherit;");
                        css.append("}");
                    }
                    else
                        css.append(".ScrolledGrid-frozen { }");

                    css.append("th.ScrolledGrid-frozen { background-color: white; }");

                    cssText.setData(css.toString());


                    if (!addedClass) {
                        NodeList<TableRowElement> rows;
                        TableRowElement row;
                        TableCellElement cell;

                        rows = getTableHeadElement().getRows();
                        for (int i = 0; i < rows.getLength(); ++i) {
                            row = rows.getItem(i);
                            cell = row.getCells().getItem(0);
                            cell.setInnerHTML("<div>" + cell.getInnerHTML() + "</div>");
                            cell.addClassName("ScrolledGrid-frozen");
                        }

                        rows = getTableBodyElement().getRows();
                        for (int i = 0; i < rows.getLength(); ++i) {
                            row = rows.getItem(i);
                            cell = row.getCells().getItem(0);

                            cell.addClassName("ScrolledGrid-frozen");
                        }
                        addedClass = true;
                    }

                    currentScrollLeft = scrollLeft;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, some CSS values are hard-coded.

Comment: +1 for the awesome code BUT it flickers like hell when I scroll(horizontal) the table. Any ideas to make scrolling smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Yuri's solution to achieve the following goals:

- does not flicker
- copes with arbitrary row-heights
- works with SelectionModel
- more uniform solution

It does not mess with the columns itself, but instead shows arbitrary "frozen" information on row-level.

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.*;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ScrollEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ScrollHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DataGrid;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DefaultCellTableBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HeaderPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollPanel;

/**
 * @author Daniel Lintner
 *
 * A DataGrid extension with the ability to display some row-level-information
 * when scrolling left (horizontal), hence important columns out of sight of the user.
 */
public class FrozenDataGrid extends DataGrid
{
    //textnode getting updated dynamically when scolling horizontally
    private Text cssText;

    //the latest scroll-position
    private int currentScrollLeft = 0;

    //an object extracting String-info from your rowdata
    private FrozenValueProvider valueProvider;

    //inject basic styling into the document - once
    //this is how the frozen row-info looks like
    static
    {
        Text baseCss = Document.get().createTextNode("");
        StyleElement styleElement = Document.get().createStyleElement();
        styleElement.setType("text/css");
        styleElement.appendChild(baseCss);

        StringBuilder css = new StringBuilder();
        css.append(".ScrolledGrid-base {");
        css.append("position: absolute;");
        css.append("background-color: gray;");
        css.append("padding: .3em;");
        css.append("padding-left: .5em;");
        css.append("padding-right: .5em;");
        css.append("border-radius: 3px 3px;");
        css.append("transition: opacity 500ms;");
        css.append("color: white;");
        css.append("margin-top: 2px;");
        css.append("white-space: nowrap;");
        css.append("}");
        baseCss.setData(css.toString());
        Document.get().getBody().insertFirst(styleElement);
    }

    public FrozenDataGrid()
    {
        super();
        init();
    }

    public FrozenDataGrid(int pageSize, DataGrid.Resources resources)
    {
        super(pageSize, resources);
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        //create a css textnode
        cssText = Document.get().createTextNode("");

        //create dynamic css Style
        StyleElement styleElement = Document.get().createStyleElement();
        styleElement.setType("text/css");
        styleElement.appendChild(cssText);

        //append the initial style condition
        //todo the name of this style might be built dynamically per instance - if multiple grid-instances exist/not the use-case by now
        StringBuilder css = new StringBuilder();
        css.append(".ScrolledGrid-frozen {");
        css.append("opacity:0;");
        css.append("}");
        cssText.setData(css.toString());

        //set a custom CellTableBuilder in order to inject the info-div to the row
        setTableBuilder(new DefaultCellTableBuilder(this)
        {
            @Override
            public void buildRowImpl(final Object rowValue, final int absRowIndex)
            {
                //do what DefaultCellTableBuilder does
                super.buildRowImpl(rowValue, absRowIndex);

                //only do something if there is a valueProvider
                if(valueProvider != null) {
                    //we do this deferred because this row has to created first in order to access it
                    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void execute()
                        {
                            createInfoDiv(getTableBodyElement().getRows().getItem(absRowIndex % getPageSize()), rowValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        //fetch the ScrollPanel from the grid
        HeaderPanel headerPanel = (HeaderPanel) getWidget();
        headerPanel.getElement().insertFirst(styleElement);
        final ScrollPanel scrollPanel = (ScrollPanel) headerPanel.getContentWidget();

        //setup a timer handling the left-offset-css thing
        //we use a timer to be able to cancel this operation -> e.g. continuous scroll
        final Timer timer = new Timer(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                StringBuilder css = new StringBuilder();

                //we need to left-offset the info-divs
                if (scrollPanel.getHorizontalScrollPosition() > 100)
                {
                    css.append(".ScrolledGrid-frozen {");
                    css.append("left: ").append(3 + scrollPanel.getHorizontalScrollPosition()).append("px;");
                    css.append("opacity: 1;");
                    css.append("}");
                }
                //we are close to the leftmost scroll position: info hidden
                else
                {
                    css.append(".ScrolledGrid-frozen {");
                    css.append("opacity:0;");
                    css.append("}");
                }

                cssText.setData(css.toString());
            }
        };

        //track scrolling
        scrollPanel.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event)
            {
                //cancel previous actions to scroll events
                if(timer.isRunning())
                    timer.cancel();

                //actual horizontal scrollposition
                int scrollLeft = scrollPanel.getHorizontalScrollPosition();

                //a horizontal scroll takes places
                if (scrollLeft != currentScrollLeft)
                {
                    //first we hide the row-info
                    StringBuilder css = new StringBuilder();
                    css.append(".ScrolledGrid-frozen {");
                    css.append("opacity:0;");
                    css.append("}");
                    cssText.setData(css.toString());

                    //render left offset after a delay
                    timer.schedule(500);

                    //remember the current horizontal position
                    currentScrollLeft = scrollLeft;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void createInfoDiv(TableRowElement row, Object value)
    {
        //create a div element and add value and style to it
        DivElement div = Document.get().createDivElement();
        div.setInnerText(valueProvider.getFrozenValue(value));
        div.addClassName("ScrolledGrid-base");
        div.addClassName("ScrolledGrid-frozen");

        //we add it to the first child of the row, because added as child of the row directly
        // confuses the CellTable with coordinating header positions
        row.getFirstChildElement().insertFirst(div);
    }

    public void setFrozenValueProvider(FrozenValueProvider valueProvider) {

        this.valueProvider = valueProvider;
    }

    public interface FrozenValueProvider<T>{
        String getFrozenValue(T data);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps developers on this rarely and unsatisfactorily solved problem.
And... there is still room for improvement left.

Cheers Dan